# Cloud suited for benchmarking

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-web-services, benchmark

Sorry for possible double post : I moved this question from stackoverflow, since it fits better here.

I use Amazon EC2 as my working machine, which is all dandy. But I also need to run CPU intensive benchmarks and here EC2 is not suited, since the hardware can change between instance boots. I have seen as much as 20-30% variation from day to day in very bad cases, but generally the performance is reasonable similar.

Do you know of any cloud which would guarantee consistence performance ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer, but just a confirmation that large performance variations do exist in the EC2 cloud. From experience (feedback) as an EC2 vendor I believe that this variation exists across all machine types. I doubt you will see a difference with other cloud vendors, as the whole concept of cloud is that machines just run anywhere that CPU/memory is available, and therefore variability in hardware and physical box location will tend to come into play. If your benchmarking is very tied to the hardware then you may be better off to just use a local VM on your desktop.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I agree the idea behind cloud may go against this idea, but I was thinking some vendor might offer some reserved CPU pool's for extra pay. Just wanted to check I was not missing out.

Comment: Some vendors do offer minimum cpu resource- however, they will also allow you to burst as well, hence why your seeing different results. Far as I am aware, this would be the same no matter what the provider.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud basically a VPS where consistency is still questionable.

Since you require a consistent H/W, might as well rent a dedicated. It will be more expensive and wasted money for unused time but those things is not your main concern.